# why am i getting this error using next and MONGODB AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, axios

**my API code to connect tp MONGODB**

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
async function haandler(req, res) {
  console.log("first");
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const data = req.body;

    console.log(data);
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(
      "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.df9aj2h.mongodb.net/quiz?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    );

    const db = client.db();
    const dataCollection = db.collection("authentication");
    const result = await dataCollection.insertOne({ data });
    console.log(result);
    client.close();
    res.status(201).json("data saved succesfully");
  }
}

export default haandler;
```

**this is the component that is sending axios request**

```
import axios from "axios";
const Authentication = () => {
  const dataGether = async (data: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    score: number;
  }) => {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/pj-api", data);
  };

  return <FormItem onDataGetter={dataGether} />;
};

export default Authentication;
```

**the error i got in console**

```
settle.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) 
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Request failed with status code 500"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
: 
{data: '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style data-next-hide-f…p":true,"scriptLoader":[]}\x3C/script></body></html>', status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:125:66)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
```

i tried to change the IP address to access from any where . i also changed the data to be more simple . i also read the answers of other questions but i didnt get my solotion to solve this error

Comment: `Request failed with status code 500` that's a server error ... what is happening in `settle.js` line `19`? You haven't shown any `axios` in your code, but the error is clearly resulting from an axios call

Comment: It is likely `bad auth`. Try connecting with Compass using your credentials to make sure.

Comment: thanks for answering . I added component that contains axios request  @Jaromanda